# how can I access the arrangement inside other array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, state

I receive an arrangement to later separate it in two each argument, at the end of this first part I have an arrangement with more arrangements inside, each arrangement inside has maximum two data

```
var recurso = this.state.patrones
    var patrones = []
    var patron = []
    var a
    var b
    for (let j = 0; j < recurso.length; j++) {
        for (let i = 0; i < recurso[j].length; i++) {
            if (recurso[j].charCodeAt(i) === 40) {
                a = recurso[j].substring(i, recurso[j].indexOf(',')).replace('(', '')
            } else if (recurso[j].charCodeAt(i) === 44) {
                b = recurso[j].substring(i, recurso[j].indexOf(')')).replace(',', '')
                patron.push([a,b])
                this.setState({
                    patronesSeparados: patrones.concat(patron)
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

After doing that, if I print my patron variable I have this in console:

```
console.log(this.state.patronesSeparados) 
    (6) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)]
    0: (2) ["1.2", "3.0"]
    1: (2) ["0.5", "0.5"]
    2: (2) ["2.3", "3.1"]
    3: (2) ["2.0", "2.5"]
    4: (2) ["2.0", "2.8"]
    5: (2) ["1.0", "1.3"]
    length: 6
```

After I do that, I don't know how to access the arrangements that are inside because I do this:

```
var recurso = this.state.patronesSeparados
console.log(recurso[0][0])
```

If that gives me error then I don't know how to access the internal arrangements

```
> react-dom.development.js:4091 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
> '0' of undefined
>     at PracticaDos.clasificaNorma (PracticaDos.js:83)
>     at PracticaDos.handleSubmit (PracticaDos.js:149)
>     at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945)
>     at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994)
>     at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056)
>     at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4070)
>     at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:8243)
>     at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:8275)
>     at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:8288)
>     at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:8299)
>     at react-dom.development.js:8508
>     at batchedEventUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:22396)
>     at batchedEventUpdates (react-dom.development.js:3745)
>     at dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem (react-dom.development.js:8507)
>     at attemptToDispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:6005)
>     at dispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:5924)
>     at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:646)
>     at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11276)
>     at discreteUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:22413)
>     at discreteUpdates (react-dom.development.js:3756)
>     at dispatchDiscreteEvent (react-dom.development.js:5889)
```

Comment: check the recurso is an array which is the exception?

Comment: What's the error that you are getting?

Comment: I will edit the question and put the error there @AmaarshallYaswankar

Comment: Try printing recurso and check if that still holds an array

Comment: In the question I put the result in the print console recurso